# timeout error for growing database size

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have an application which is running under productive environment.The application has a web service which takes in data and saves the data in MS SQL database for future processing. This web service is used by our client to send the data. We receive around 80 records per seconds.

Initially the application was working fine and the size of the database was 1 GB. The application is in production environment for around 6 months now and the database size has reached to 15 GB. Now all the operations on the database are taking more time. Clients are getting timeout error for the web service due to database slow speed.

Please suggest a solution so that we can handle such a application where database size increases gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Re-build the indexes on tables. 
Rebuilding the indexes allows database server to search faster into the database. You should periodically rebuild the indexes so that db engine gets the required "quick references" to complete the search in timely manner.